# Copy Qt Libraries to output directory with make

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a qt .pro file which looks something like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = demoqt
DESTDIR = ./debug
QT += core gui
CONFIG += debug
DEFINES += QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT QT_DLL
HEADERS += ./src/MainWindow.h
SOURCES += ./src/MainWindow.cpp ./src/main.cpp
```

Its building successfully under windows with the following .bat:

```
@echo off
echo Setting up a Qt environment...
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\4.8.3
set PATH=C:\Qt\4.8.3\bin;%PATH%
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
qmake
nmake
```

I have absolutely no experience with makefiles what so ever - I completely winged this. The problem I'm experiencing is that the necessary Qt DLL files are not getting copied to the output directory. As such, when I execute my executable file, I get errors such as `The program can't start because QtGuid4.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinsalling the program to fix this problem.`

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a line in the .bat file at the end to copy QtGuid4.dll (and any others) to the output directory.

If it's a personal project and you're not worried about installation/distribution issues, you can just copy them once manually to the Windows system directory (actual name depends on os version).

Comment: you could also just create a bat file that includes the path to your <QtDir>\bin directory in your PATH variable just as you have for when building the program. This bat file would then call your program.